# Initilize a vector of std future at construction

Tags: c++, asynchronous, vector, future

Consider following code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <future>

using namespace std;

void someFunction(){

  //do something
}

int main() {

  vector<future<void>> tasks1;

  tasks1.emplace_back(async(launch::async, someFunction));
  
  vector<future<void>> tasks2{ async(launch::async, someFunction) }; //doesn't compile

  vector<future<void>> tasks3{ move(async(launch::async, someFunction)) }; //doesn't compile

}
```

Why doesn't task2 and task3 compile? I would assume that the move constructor is called in tasks3 but it is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`future` cannot be copied, only can be moved.

By

```
{ async(launch::async, someFunction) }
```

`future` is stored in `initializer_list`. All elements of initializer list are considered to be const, [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list). `const` object as a source object can be only copied into the target vector, not moved, that is why the code compilation failed.

Comment: If I use move in the construction, can't the initilizer_list store the rvalue and do a perfect forwarding?

Comment: The code fails, when trying to copy content of `initializer_list` to the `vector` (not when storing futures in `{}`). Copy is made then, not move operation - all in `{}` is treated as const objects.